# Laravel + VUE, works on locally but not in Server

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a problem with Laravel + Vue, I have uploaded an application that works locally but the VUE part does not work on the server.

When you have to upload the part of the VUE files it does not load anything

With this example, type HELLO, but the part of the VUE component that would have to load inside the DIV does not load it

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("css/app.css ")}}">
</head>

<body >

  <p>HELLO</p>

  <div class="" id="app">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <script src="{{asset("js/app.js")}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey~ What are errors reported by the browser console? Have you run `npm run prod` in your server?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run composer install and npm install ?
if you have ssh run the following command before deploying your code --> npm run dev. However, when you deploy to the live server with real users, run this command --> npm run production.
if you work in shared hosting and don't have ssh , the solution is almost always "do it locally, upload it when done".